# Is there a demo of thrift to send and receive message?

Tags: java, thrift

I am currently learning apache thrift. But all demos I've got are about RPC. My question is, is it able to send and receive message, say a struct or a string? (There is just a struct definition in .thrift file)
A demo in java is appreciated.
thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thrift is RPC protocol, not a messaging one. In theory you could implement messaging a top of it, but if your needs are message oriented, than you could be better of to use some messaging protocol like AMQP.

If on the other hand you would like to know if you could pass more complex data structures in your RPC calls via thirft, than answer is yes, by all means.

Comment: you mean I can send message by RPC call? So I wonder if Serializing message by thrift and then send by AMQP is a good scheme?

Comment: yes, that seems more natural way if your domain is mainly messaging one. You could also investigate if some other serialization is more natural fit to your domain, like json, protocol buffers, or something else.